# Jquery Autocomplete custom column filtering not working

Tags: html, jquery, datatable, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to create a text dropdown with autocomplete feature to filter the fields.But it's not working properly. The custom filter search function is also calling the previous filter value.Code working for the static data but not for dynamic input text box data.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<head> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 


<script src="fil2.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="filter_css.css"> 

</head> 

<body> 
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
    <form>
    <thead> 
        
        <tr> 

            <th>Name</th> 

            <th>Position</th> 

            <th>Office</th> 

            <th>Age</th> 

            <th>Start date</th> 

            <th>Salary</th> 

        </tr> 
        
    </thead> 

     

    <tbody> 
        
        <tr> 

            <td><input type="text" value="Tiger"></td> 

            <td><input type="text" value="System Architect"></td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>61</td> 

            <td>2011/04/25</td> 

            <td>$320,800</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Garrett Winters</td> 

            <td>Accountant</td> 

            <td>Tokyo</td> 

            <td>63</td> 

            <td>2011/07/25</td> 

            <td>$170,750</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Ashton Cox</td> 

            <td>Junior Technical Author</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>66</td> 

            <td>2009/01/12</td> 

            <td>$86,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Cedric Kelly</td> 

            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>22</td> 

            <td>2012/03/29</td> 

            <td>$433,060</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Airi Satou</td> 

            <td>Accountant</td> 

            <td>Tokyo</td> 

            <td>33</td> 

            <td>2008/11/28</td> 

            <td>$162,700</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Brielle Williamson</td> 

            <td>Integration Specialist</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>61</td> 

            <td>2012/12/02</td> 

            <td>$372,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Herrod Chandler</td> 

            <td>Sales Assistant</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>59</td> 

            <td>2012/08/06</td> 

            <td>$137,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Rhona Davidson</td> 

            <td>Integration Specialist</td> 

            <td>Tokyo</td> 

            <td>55</td> 

            <td>2010/10/14</td> 

            <td>$327,900</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Colleen Hurst</td> 

            <td>Javascript Developer</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>39</td> 

            <td>2009/09/15</td> 

            <td>$205,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Sonya Frost</td> 

            <td>Software Engineer</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>23</td> 

            <td>2008/12/13</td> 

            <td>$103,600</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Jena Gaines</td> 

            <td>Office Manager</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>30</td> 

            <td>2008/12/19</td> 

            <td>$90,560</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Quinn Flynn</td> 

            <td>Support Lead</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>22</td> 

            <td>2013/03/03</td> 

            <td>$342,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Charde Marshall</td> 

            <td>Regional Director</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>36</td> 

            <td>2008/10/16</td> 

            <td>$470,600</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Haley Kennedy</td> 

            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>43</td> 

            <td>2012/12/18</td> 

            <td>$313,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td> 

            <td>Regional Director</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>19</td> 

            <td>2010/03/17</td> 

            <td>$385,750</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Michael Silva</td> 

            <td>Marketing Designer</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>66</td> 

            <td>2012/11/27</td> 

            <td>$198,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Paul Byrd</td> 

            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>64</td> 

            <td>2010/06/09</td> 

            <td>$725,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Gloria Little</td> 

            <td>Systems Administrator</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>59</td> 

            <td>2009/04/10</td> 

            <td>$237,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Bradley Greer</td> 

            <td>Software Engineer</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>41</td> 

            <td>2012/10/13</td> 

            <td>$132,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Dai Rios</td> 

            <td>Personnel Lead</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>35</td> 

            <td>2012/09/26</td> 

            <td>$217,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td> 

            <td>Development Lead</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>30</td> 

            <td>2011/09/03</td> 

            <td>$345,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Yuri Berry</td> 

            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>40</td> 

            <td>2009/06/25</td> 

            <td>$675,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Caesar Vance</td> 

            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>21</td> 

            <td>2011/12/12</td> 

            <td>$106,450</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Doris Wilder</td> 

            <td>Sales Assistant</td> 

            <td>Sidney</td> 

            <td>23</td> 

            <td>2010/09/20</td> 

            <td>$85,600</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Angelica Ramos</td> 

            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>47</td> 

            <td>2009/10/09</td> 

            <td>$1,200,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Gavin Joyce</td> 

            <td>Developer</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>42</td> 

            <td>2010/12/22</td> 

            <td>$92,575</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Jennifer Chang</td> 

            <td>Regional Director</td> 

            <td>Singapore</td> 

            <td>28</td> 

            <td>2010/11/14</td> 

            <td>$357,650</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Brenden Wagner</td> 

            <td>Software Engineer</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>28</td> 

            <td>2011/06/07</td> 

            <td>$206,850</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Fiona Green</td> 

            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>48</td> 

            <td>2010/03/11</td> 

            <td>$850,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Shou Itou</td> 

            <td>Regional Marketing</td> 

            <td>Tokyo</td> 

            <td>20</td> 

            <td>2011/08/14</td> 

            <td>$163,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Michelle House</td> 

            <td>Integration Specialist</td> 

            <td>Sidney</td> 

            <td>37</td> 

            <td>2011/06/02</td> 

            <td>$95,400</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Suki Burks</td> 

            <td>Developer</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>53</td> 

            <td>2009/10/22</td> 

            <td>$114,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td> 

            <td>Technical Author</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>27</td> 

            <td>2011/05/07</td> 

            <td>$145,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Gavin Cortez</td> 

            <td>Team Leader</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>22</td> 

            <td>2008/10/26</td> 

            <td>$235,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Martena Mccray</td> 

            <td>Post-Sales support</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>46</td> 

            <td>2011/03/09</td> 

            <td>$324,050</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Unity Butler</td> 

            <td>Marketing Designer</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>47</td> 

            <td>2009/12/09</td> 

            <td>$85,675</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Howard Hatfield</td> 

            <td>Office Manager</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>51</td> 

            <td>2008/12/16</td> 

            <td>$164,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Hope Fuentes</td> 

            <td>Secretary</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>41</td> 

            <td>2010/02/12</td> 

            <td>$109,850</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Vivian Harrell</td> 

            <td>Financial Controller</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>62</td> 

            <td>2009/02/14</td> 

            <td>$452,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Timothy Mooney</td> 

            <td>Office Manager</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>37</td> 

            <td>2008/12/11</td> 

            <td>$136,200</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td> 

            <td>Director</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>65</td> 

            <td>2008/09/26</td> 

            <td>$645,750</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Olivia Liang</td> 

            <td>Support Engineer</td> 

            <td>Singapore</td> 

            <td>64</td> 

            <td>2011/02/03</td> 

            <td>$234,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Bruno Nash</td> 

            <td>Software Engineer</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>38</td> 

            <td>2011/05/03</td> 

            <td>$163,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td> 

            <td>Support Engineer</td> 

            <td>Tokyo</td> 

            <td>37</td> 

            <td>2009/08/19</td> 

            <td>$139,575</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Thor Walton</td> 

            <td>Developer</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>61</td> 

            <td>2013/08/11</td> 

            <td>$98,540</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Finn Camacho</td> 

            <td>Support Engineer</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>47</td> 

            <td>2009/07/07</td> 

            <td>$87,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Serge Baldwin</td> 

            <td>Data Coordinator</td> 

            <td>Singapore</td> 

            <td>64</td> 

            <td>2012/04/09</td> 

            <td>$138,575</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Zenaida Frank</td> 

            <td>Software Engineer</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>63</td> 

            <td>2010/01/04</td> 

            <td>$125,250</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Zorita Serrano</td> 

            <td>Software Engineer</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>56</td> 

            <td>2012/06/01</td> 

            <td>$115,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td> 

            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>43</td> 

            <td>2013/02/01</td> 

            <td>$75,650</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Cara Stevens</td> 

            <td>Sales Assistant</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>46</td> 

            <td>2011/12/06</td> 

            <td>$145,600</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Hermione Butler</td> 

            <td>Regional Director</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>47</td> 

            <td>2011/03/21</td> 

            <td>$356,250</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Lael Greer</td> 

            <td>Systems Administrator</td> 

            <td>London</td> 

            <td>21</td> 

            <td>2009/02/27</td> 

            <td>$103,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Jonas Alexander</td> 

            <td>Developer</td> 

            <td>San Francisco</td> 

            <td>30</td> 

            <td>2010/07/14</td> 

            <td>$86,500</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Shad Decker</td> 

            <td>Regional Director</td> 

            <td>Edinburgh</td> 

            <td>51</td> 

            <td>2008/11/13</td> 

            <td>$183,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Michael Bruce</td> 

            <td>Javascript Developer</td> 

            <td>Singapore</td> 

            <td>29</td> 

            <td>2011/06/27</td> 

            <td>$183,000</td> 

        </tr> 

        <tr> 

            <td>Donna Snider</td> 

            <td>Customer Support</td> 

            <td>New York</td> 

            <td>27</td> 

            <td>2011/01/25</td> 

            <td>$112,000</td> 

        </tr> 

    </tbody> 
    </form>
</table>
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        var allcolsData=$('#example').DataTable().columns().data();
        this.api()
        .columns()
        .every(function (){
            var column = this;
            var c_idx=column.index();
            var colData=allcolsData[c_idx];
            $.each(colData,function(i,v){
                    var p=v.split('value="');
                    if(p.length==1){
                        colData[i]=(p[0]);
                    }
                    else{
                        colData[i]=(p[1].split('">')[0]);
                    }
            });
            colData=Array.from(new Set(colData)).sort();
            var select = $('<input type="text" />').appendTo($(column.header()))
            .autocomplete({
                source: colData,
                minLength: 0,
                scroll: true,
                close: function(event, ui)  {
                // Close event fires when selection options closes
                    $('input')[0].value = ""; // Clear the input field 
                }
            }).focus(function() {
                $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
            })
            .on('autocompleteselect', function (e,ui) {
                
                //console.log(ui.item);
                    var filterValue = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(ui.item.value);
                    console.log(filterValue);
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                        console.log(filterValue+new Date($.now()));
                        if(data[c_idx].indexOf(filterValue) != -1){
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                        
                    });
                    column.draw();
                    
                    
            });
            

        });
        
    },
});});
```

Here is the codepen link- https://codepen.io/prakshu/pen/JjLjdoJ

Filter autocomplete work fine for first time but not next time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your on('autocompleteselect' to

```
.on("autocompleteselect keyup", function (e, ui) {
          var val = "";
          if (ui) {
            val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(ui.item.value);
          }
          if (column.search() !== val) {
            column.search(val).draw();
          }
        });
```